# how handle 12-bit image from MIPI camera?

Tags: c++, image-processing, camera

Actually, I use a Gige camera. That camera provide images in `unsigned char*`, this mean a bit depth of 8. I develop in c/c++.

I am going to receive a new one, but that camera is different. This one provides `void*`, with a bit depth of 12. Can I cast the `void*` like that :

```
unsigned short* img ;
img = (unsigned short*) camera.GetImage() ; /**camera.GetImage() is void*/
```

It is new for me, and I have been never using raw format. Does cast is a good idea ? I need to access at each pixel, and I don't how handle pixel with `void*`.

I suggest to cast with `unsigned short*` because of the depth. The pixel of the camera are encoded on 12. If I cast with `unsigned char*`, I would lose information.

Thank you for your help !

### UPDATE

Thank you a lot for all your details. As I am a beginner, your answer help me a lot to find other ways to investigate.

I am working on jetson TX2, and the bit location is a reflection of the actual hardware.

For my part, the pixel data is concatenated in 16bits. The output of the jetson TX2 is :

```
              ONE PIXEL

|              16 bits                          |
D5-D4-D3-D2-D1-D0-D11-D10-0-0-D11-D10-D9-D8-D7-D6
```

My goal is not to display the image. Below the explanation of my process :

> 1 - Take 5 times the same image ;
>
> 2 - Calculation of the average image ;
>
> 3 - Bad pixels correction ;
>
> 4 - Flat field correction ;
>
> 4 - Send final image through socket ;

In a thread, I acquire images. In an other thread, I apply image processing and in an other one, I send image through socket. I implemented all the process.

I didn't use libraries like openCV because I did some specifics process. I need to handle all pixels of the image, and I wonder if it is very efficient to convert the `.raw` in `unsigned short*`, to adapt the image to my code.

The 'packing' was never a question because my previous camera provides images in an `unsigned char*`. Do you think that I should convert the `void*` into `unsigned short*` ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: You may get a better answer if you are more specific about which camera model and which specific API call you are using with links to both. You should also check whether your data are *"packed"* tightly together or not. I mean do two 12-bit pixels fit in 3 bytes (24 bits) or do two 12-bit pixels require 4 bytes (32 bits).

Comment: Sorry, the camera is :  FSM-IMX304M 
Here the link for the camera https://www.framos.com/media/pdf/c4/bf/05/FSM-IMX304_Datasheet_v1-0g_BriefDPJ6pgNMQObQQ.pdf

I use libsv, it is V4L2 streamlined. There is no specific documentation for libsv, only header files.  

Moreover, it is a monochrome camera.

If my data are "packet" it means that I can get 2 images when, I call the function GetImage() ? I didn't see anything about that in the documentation

Comment: The only thing information about the data :
/**
 * @brief This struct represents a single image
 * 
 * This structure is retrieved by calling GetImage() function
 */
struct IImage 
{
    void* data;                     /**< Raw pointer to buffer */ [...]
};

Comment: What I meant about *"packing"* is whether the 12-bits from the first pixel are tightly packed against the 12-bits for the second pixel, or whether the final 4-bits of the first pixel are just empty so each pixel always takes a full 2 bytes.

Comment: It might be necessary to experiment. Make a picture that's all bright white, and another that's as dark as you make it. Then compare the first 100 bytes of the image.

Comment: I have updated my post to give more informations about the packing, and have some advices. Thank you both !

Comment: You have two D10 and two D11...

Comment: Yes and it is normal. It is how jetson TX2 encodes informations.

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information in your post to answer your question. 
Here are the possible packing for 12-bits pixels:

## Efficient packing

```
Bit0     Bit11     Bit23      Bit35        Bit47     Bit59     Bit71     Bit83      Bit95
[ Pixel0   | Pixel1  | Pixel2    | Pixel3  | Pixel4   | Pixel5  | Pixel6  |  Pixel7 ]  (that is 8 pixels per 96bits or 3 32-bits word)
```

## Easy to use packing

```
Bit0    Bit11     Bit23    Bit32     Bit43     Bit55     Bit63     
[ Pixel0   | Pixel1  | 0    | Pixel3  | Pixel4   | 0      ]  (that is 2 pixels per 32-bits word)
```

## Dumb packing

```
Bit0    Bit11     Bit16    Bit27     Bit31          
[ Pixel0   |  0    | Pixel1  |  0      ]  (that is 1 pixels per 16-bits word)
```

You have to read the datasheet of your camera to figure which packing is being used. Once this is done, you also need to figure out the endianness of the data for transmitting the data words. For example, in a little endian system, you'll the least significant byte first. For a big endian system, you'll get the most significant byte first. You'll need to adapt your pixel extraction code to fit your machine's endianness.

Extracting pixel is done quite simply once you have figured out the packing and endianness with bit shifting and mask.

Since you have asked for a C++ solution, here's a any-bit extractor from a memory stream, you'll need to adjust for the packing and endianness:

```
struct BitStream
{
    const uint8 * begin;
    const uint8 * end;
    size_t pos;
    BitStream(const uint8 * bits, size_t len) : begin(bits), end(bits + len), pos(0) {}
    // get value from bitstream coded on len bits
    uint32 get(uint8 len)
    {
        size_t byte_offset = pos/8;
        uint8 bit_pos = pos % 8;
        uint8 bit_avail = 8 - bit_pos;
        if (begin+byte_offset >= end) return 0;
        if (bit_avail >= len)
        {
            uint32 value = begin[byte_offset];
            uint8 mask = ~(0xff << len) << bit_pos;
            value = value & mask;
            value = value >> bit_pos;
            pos = pos + len;
            return value;
        }
        else
        {
            uint32 value = get(bit_avail);
            value = value | (get(len - bit_avail)<<bit_avail);
            return value;
        }
    }
    void skip(uint8 len) { pos += len; }
    bool done() const { return (begin + pos/8) >= end; }
};
```

If there is endianness mismatch between the camera and your machine, you'll need to swap the returned pixel like this:

```
BitStream bs((const uint8*)camera.getImage(), camera.getImageLen());
// Get pixel
uint16 pixel = (uint16)bs.get(12);
// Comment the line below if the endianness is the same
pixel = ((pixel & 0xFF00) >> 8) | (pixel << 8);
// Skip the stuffing zero bits depending on packing format, here I assume dumb packing
bs.skip(4);
```

Comment: I think you swapped "easy to use packing" and "dumb packing. Both have the same space efficiency (75%) but only the "12 bits per pixel, 4 bits padding" format can be interpreted by a trivial cast to `std::uint16_t`. Also, I'd expect the padding before the MSB, not below the LSB.

Comment: Well, the point is that, without datasheet information, it's impossible to know the packing for sure. So I've presented many different "possible" packing, obviously, not all. The notion of MSB and LSB is not specified here (especially if the image is stored as LE, where byte swap will happen at byte boundaries). So yes, it's a simple *solution* to let the OP understand better how to deal with his problem, not to solve it since I don't know the parameters of it.

Comment: "Easy to use" is because this format (24 bits on 32bits) directly map to some GPU's texture format so if the goal is to display the image, no bit twiddling work is required. If you need to extract each pixel one by one, I wonder all of the packing above are similarly complex (it's ~ the same code with the class I've shown)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for updating your question.

If, as it now seems, each 12-bit pixel is fully contained in a 16-bit unsigned short with 4-bits of padding, then "yes" unsigned short is definitely the way to go. I don't know if your environment has `uint16_t` or not but that is guaranteed to be **exactly** 16-bits (which I feel is better) whereas `unsigned short` is *"at least"* 16-bits.

Now you just need to do some ANDing and shifting...

Comment: Thank you Mark Setchell.


I will try, and I will update the post when I will find a solution